# how to check whether the input is found or not found in the directory using pinky (there are inputs, but the user is not there)

Tags: bash

what I want is to input a username and if the user cannot be found, the FNAME should be not found, but when I did the tester, the NOTFOUND never shows up, the tester was made by someone else and should have no problem.

```
function fname()
{
#if argument passed canot be found among sessions logged in
result=$(pinky -f "$1")
result_length="${#result}"
#if the result length is not equal to zero means there are some values
elif [ "$result_length" != 0 ]
then
        FNAME="$(pinky -f $1 | awk '{print $2}')"
        return 0
elif [ ! -f "$result" ]
then
        FNAME="NOTFOUND"
        return 0
fi
}
```

I tried to check the result but only ERROR and the user's first name can be displayed, the NOTFOUND never shows up even when I put a wrong input. is it because the ${# result} never display 0?
fname
Function status code is ==1==  FNAME value is ==ERROR==
[[[[ WORKS - but user id is not found ]]]]

---

fname nouser
Function status code is ==0==  FNAME value is ====
[[[[ WORKS - user id is found ]]]]

---

fname zo9
Function status code is ==0==  FNAME value is ==Zo==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is on this line:

```
elif [ ! -f "$result" ]
```

This literally means "else if `$result` is not a file."  Since you are setting result to the output of pinky, this is obviously not doing what you think it does.  Since you are checking whether the variable result is blank or not in the original if statement, all you need here is `else`.

Also, there is a built in way to check for a blank variable using test (`[`).  You could test with the `-n` option.  It would be cleaner to use that in your `if` block like this:

```
if [ -n "$result" ]; then
    # found
else
    # not found
fi
```

Then, there is no need for the `result_length` variable.

Also, there is no need to re-run pinky for awk.  You have the result of pinky stored in your `result` variable.  All you need to do is send the variable into awk with a here-string.  Something like this:

```
FNAME="$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$result")"
```